# Translate mysql query to joooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

hello id like write it in jooq

```
select * from TABLE group by TABLE.ID HAVING max(TABLE.CREATED_AT) and TABLE.BOX=1;
```

but jooq in having clouse expect condition, and DSL.max() returns aggregate function...

```
dslContext.select(*)
                .from(TABLE)
                .groupBy(TABLE.CREATED_AT)
                .having(DSL.condition(max(TABLE.CREATED_AT)))\
```

gives compile time error

Comment: But your initial query makes no sense, doesn't it? Why can't you recover just the record with ID = 1 without the other conditions? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: ah ive made error while anonymizing it, multiple BOX'es with id =1